# Estimating optimal parameters for delay differential equation using Python

Tags: python, curve-fitting, differential-equations, lmfit

I am trying to obtain optimal parameters (k1 and k2 in this case) for a delay differential equation (DDE) or, in other words, I am trying to fit a curve on a DDE. I am using `ddeint` for solving DDE and `lmfit.minimize` for minimizing the residual.

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit

def model(A, t, params):               #returns dA/dt

    k1 = params["k1"].value
    k2 = params["k2"].value
    k3 = params["k3"].value
       
    P = get_P(t)  #get_P is a function which returns the value of P at any time

    Pt1 = get_P(t-1)

    return (k1*P)*A(t) + (k2*Pt1)*A(t-1)

params = Parameters()
params.add('A0', a_constant)     
params.add('k1', value= 0)
params.add('k2', value= 0)


t = np.arange(1955, 2020)

g= lambda t: const   # function returns a constant value for t<t0

def dde(t, params):
    Area = ddeint(model_new,new_g,t, fargs=(params,)) 
    return Area

def residual(params, t, obs_A):    #obs_A is the array of observed values of area
    A0 = params["A0"].value
    modeled = dde(t, params) 
    return (modeled.ravel() - obs_A)

res = minimize(residual, params, args=(t, obs_A,), method='leastsq') #minimzing residual
```

This script gives me the following error-

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-803-cc4b44f3f4be> in <module>
----> 1 res = minimize(residual, params, args=(tt1, obs_A,), method='leastsq')

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\lmfit\minimizer.py in minimize(fcn, params, method, args, kws, iter_cb, scale_covar, nan_policy, reduce_fcn, calc_covar, max_nfev, **fit_kws)
   2503                        nan_policy=nan_policy, reduce_fcn=reduce_fcn,
   2504                        calc_covar=calc_covar, max_nfev=max_nfev, **fit_kws)
-> 2505     return fitter.minimize(method=method)

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\lmfit\minimizer.py in minimize(self, method, params, **kws)
   2283                         val.lower().startswith(user_method)):
   2284                     kwargs['method'] = val
-> 2285         return function(**kwargs)
   2286 
   2287 

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\lmfit\minimizer.py in leastsq(self, params, max_nfev, **kws)
   1644         result.call_kws = lskws
   1645         try:
-> 1646             lsout = scipy_leastsq(self.__residual, variables, **lskws)
   1647         except AbortFitException:
   1648             pass

c:\python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    399             maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
    400         retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
--> 401                                  gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    402     else:
    403         if col_deriv:

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

I am new to `ddeint` and parameter estimation using `lmfit`, so please let me know if there are any other errors in the scripts, also suggestions regarding estimating parameters are welcome.

Comment: Your example is not self-contained, what is `x_Al`? `ddeint` uses linear interpolation of the past history, which will impact the achievable error order.

Comment: @LutzLehmann x_Al is a data frame from which the initial value is obtained, anyways I changed it to a constant

Comment: There are many invalid and/or odd things in your code (try without except, `def model` that is not used, many undefined and unused variables).  Please clean up the question,  include import statements,  and verify that it gives the output you claim.  For sure, the residual function should return a float64 numpy array.